# Viewport issues

Tags: mobile, viewport

been struggling for some time now.

I'm trying to give my welcome-section the same size as the viewport, but I just can't seem to get it done, whatever I do...

Then also, the bottom is hidden under the safari menu when I check the mobile version. I used the same formula as I used before on another project, but it doesn't work here.

Can somebody clarify, please?

Many thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, grey, black);
  height: 100%;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: block-inline;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #db0b15;
}

.navbar {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-item {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

welcome-section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: ;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.subheader {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.project-list {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
  grid-column-gap: 70px;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.project-img {
  height: 120%;
  width: 120%;
}

.icon {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.profile-link: {
  color: blue;
}

#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .project-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  .project-list {
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 160px 160px;
    grid-template-rows: 120px 120px;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    _::-webkit-full-page-media,
    _:future,
     :root .safari_only {
      padding-bottom: 170px; //resize
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1c24d3937a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title id="title">Personal Portfolio - Iwan Van den Broeck</title>
</head>

<body id="body">

  <navbar id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#welcome-section">Welcome</a></li>

      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>

      <li class="navbar-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </navbar>

  <welcome-section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">

    <h1>Welcome to my Portfolio.<br><br>I am Iwan<br><br> and I'm a Web Developer<br><br></h1>

  </welcome-section>



  <projects-section id="projects">

    <p class="subheader">These are some of my projects:</p>

    <project-list class="project-list">

      <a id="tribute-page" class="project-tile center" href="https://codepen.io/iwan-van-den-broeck/full/YzZoXvY" target="blank" alt="link to Steve Jobs tribute page"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1pTGPtU4oKYReRbMnAPkeC1ll-Nor0dSo" alt="screenshot of tribute page" class="project-img"></a>

      <a id="survey-form" class="project-tile center" href="https://codepen.io/iwan-van-den-broeck/full/mdWZNPd" target="blank" alt="link to AirAsia customer satisfaction survey"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Sclylussw2JNXSSlD3qs7xABHVKx_0LV" alt="screenshot of survey form" class="project-img"></a>

      <a id="product-landing-page" class="project-tile center" href="https://codepen.io/iwan-van-den-broeck/full/NWjKdre" target="blank" alt="link to Apple landing page"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1RY4MuLY8knZk6pogcMwApjJ-fYOtTUCu" alt="screenshot of landing page" class="project-img"></a>

      <a id="technical-documentation-page" class="project-tile center" href="https://codepen.io/iwan-van-den-broeck/full/BaRaRWp" target="blank" alt="link to JS technical documentation page"><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Pxp17-rmWZqD0or3lmF2UvtPbKuCyC6l" alt="screenshot of technical documentation page" class="project-img"></a>

    </project-list>

  </projects-section>

  <contact-section id="contact">

    <p class="subheader">Contact me:</p>

    <p>Let's do some projects together! Contact me for more information.</p>

    <p id="contact-links">
      <p>
        <i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt icon"> Call me</i>
        <i class="fas fa-envelope-square icon"> Email me</i>
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin icon"> Linkedin</i>
      </p>

      <p>Click here to visit <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/iwan84" target="_blank" alt="link to my FCC-profile" id="profile-link" class="profile-link">my Profile</a>
      </p>

  </contact-section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set your `section` to `height: 100vh;` to make it the full height of your viewport.

In combination with `display: block;` it will work.

```
welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @IwanVandenBroeck Great! So the question is solved?
Please mark my answer so.